# How to pass a struct to an Uber Cadence Activity and return modified struct in workflow

Tags: struct, parameter-passing, cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

I am just trying some basic Uber Cadence samples.I am confronting with an issue as follows:
I have got an activity which receives a struct as parameter and changes values and returns modified struct.I am not able to get the modified values when executes the workflow.It is showing default values.Code snippet I tried as follows:

```
  type Product struct {
    vendor      string // "Arrows"
    productCategory string // "Clothing"
    productName string // "Shirt"
    description string // "Shirt for Gents"
    size        int    // 42    
    cost        float32// 2.00
    color       string // "Red"
    auctionOption   string // "Buy it Now"
}

// populateProduct
func newProduct() *Product {  
    p := Product{vendor:  "Arrows"}
    p.productCategory = "Clothing"
    p.productName = "Shirt"
    p.description = "Shirt for Gents"
    p.size = 42 
    p.cost = 2.00
    p.color = "Red"
    p.auctionOption = "Buy it Now"
    return &p
}

// Activity
func NewProductActivity(ctx context.Context) (*Product, error) {
    logger := activity.GetLogger(ctx)
    logger.Info("NewProductActivity started.................")
    np := newProduct()
    return np, nil
    }

    // Workflow
    func MarketPlaceWorkflow(ctx workflow.Context, name string) (string, error) {
        ctx = workflow.WithActivityOptions(ctx, activityOptions)

        logger := workflow.GetLogger(ctx)
    logger.Info("MarketPlace workflow started!................")

    // Invoking NewProductActivity
    var npActivityResult Product
    err := workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, NewProductActivity).Get(ctx, &npActivityResult)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("MarketPlace workflow NewProductActivity failed!.............", zap.Error(err))
        return "", err
    }
        logger.Info("Vendor: ", zap.String("Vendor", npActivityResult.vendor)) // It is showing default values
   return "", nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cadence and Temporal by default use [encoding/json](https://blog.golang.org/json) package to serialize and deserialize activity inputs and outputs. This package does not serialize private fields. So in your case as all the fields are private they are ignored when passed from activity to the workflow. Change your code to:

```
type Product struct {
    Vendor      string // "Arrows"
    ProductCategory string // "Clothing"
    ProductName string // "Shirt"
    Description string // "Shirt for Gents"
    Size        int    // 42    
    Cost        float32// 2.00
    Color       string // "Red"
    AuctionOption   string // "Buy it Now"
}

// populateProduct
func newProduct() *Product {  
    p := Product{Vendor:  "Arrows"}
    p.ProductCategory = "Clothing"
    p.ProductName = "Shirt"
    p.Description = "Shirt for Gents"
    p.Size = 42 
    p.Cost = 2.00
    p.Color = "Red"
    p.AuctionOption = "Buy it Now"
    return &p
}

// Activity
func NewProductActivity(ctx context.Context) (*Product, error) {
    logger := activity.GetLogger(ctx)
    logger.Info("NewProductActivity started.................")
    np := newProduct()
    return np, nil
}

// Workflow
func MarketPlaceWorkflow(ctx workflow.Context, name string) (string, error) {
    ctx = workflow.WithActivityOptions(ctx, activityOptions)

    logger := workflow.GetLogger(ctx)
    logger.Info("MarketPlace workflow started!................")

    // Invoking NewProductActivity
    var npActivityResult Product
    err := workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, NewProductActivity).Get(ctx, &npActivityResult)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("MarketPlace workflow NewProductActivity failed!.............", zap.Error(err))
        return "", err
    }
    logger.Info("Vendor: ", zap.String("Vendor", npActivityResult.Vendor))
    return "", nil
}
```

Comment: I did check  encoding/json package and done the changes as you have mentioned. It works. I do really appreciate your time and thanking you.